# Tzaziki: the drink, not the sauce

Tags: alcohol, food-identification

One night in Rome, I had the most amazing drink. It had cucumber and sugar, some unidentifiable alcohol (gin? Vodka?), and I believe mint. The menu identified it as tzaziki, but I've been unable to find it online, probably because of the eponymous sauce. Has anyone heard of the drink? Could you identify the mystery liquor?

Comment: You aren't possibly thinking of Sambuca?

Comment: The drink was probably called tzaziki because it used some of the ingredients used for the sauce; _tzatziki_ is not an Italian term, and I don't think that is the name used for that drink.

Comment: Never heard of this, but sounds really refreshing.I've located this recipe, does it sound like it? http://www.yumsugar.com/Happy-Hour-Cucumber-Cocktail-754163

Comment: It wasn't Sambuca--I have friends who were there and can confirm that it was call tzaziki. It was a clear cocktail, if that helps.

Comment: It sounds (both phonetically and by recipe) like something Greek. You might check with a local authentic (first generation) Greek restaurant.

Comment: Can you describe the drink a bit more in detail? What kind of glass was it served in? Martini, highball, shot? Over ice? Did the drink have a particular flavor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it sounds like it could be a cucumber martini or a variation of one, which does use vodka.

Here's a recipe from  [Recipes 4 Living](http://www.recipe4living.com/recipes/cool_cucumber_martini.htm) :

> Ingredients
>
> - 3 oz. Cucumber Vodka
> - 1/4 oz. Lime Juice
> - 2 slices Cucumber
> - 3 pieces Mint
> - 1/2 oz. Simple Syrup
>
> Directions
>
> Muddle mint and a cucumber slice in a cocktail shaker. Add other ingredients and ice. Shake and strain into a chilled martini glass, and garnish with a slice of cucumber and a fresh mint sprig.

You can use this as a starting point and tweak it to your liking or, alternatively, search for other cucumber martini recipes on the Internet. There are many available.

Answer (score 3):

Just a guess, too, but I've at least seen a drink that could be the one you're looking for: "Munich Mule", a variation on the "Moscow Mule" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_mule) where you just exchange the lime for strips of cucumber. I only found recipes in German - obviously invented in Munich, saw it in Berlin once - here is a translation from http://www.rezeptewiki.org/wiki/Munich_Mule:

- 4 cl Vodka
- 5 Strips of Cucumber
- Ginger Beer
- crushed ice

Put the cucumber into a highball glass, add the Vodka. Stir, add the ice and fill with Ginger Beer. Serve immediately.

There also seem to be recipes around that recommend Tonic Water, but I've never seen Mint mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

This is total hypothetical:

Mix 2.5:2.5:1 parts [Cucumber-infused Vodka]:[Whipped Cream Vodka]:Vermouth. Rub lemon rind around rim of chilled martini glass, pour, garnish, grate ginger over top. Enjoy?